# how i can use update service with restangular2

Tags: angular, restangular

hello I am creating an editing service in my angular2 application using restangular
this my service

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Project} from '../model/projects';
import {id} from "@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/utils";
import {Restangular} from 'ngx-restangular';

@Injectable()
export class updateprojectService {
project: Project;
constructor (private restangular: Restangular) {}
update(project) {
return this.restangular.one('projects').customPUT(project,{'projectid': project.id}, undefined, {'Content-Type': undefined});

}
}
```

and this is the error 
[image]

maybe the problem is to specify the id of the data to edit

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `project.id` is an object not a number. Dump it out and see what reference the number is under. Something like

```
...
return this.restangular.one('projects').customPUT(project,{'projectid': project.id.some_key}, undefined, {'Content-Type': undefined});
```

Where `some_key` is the unknown object reference.